# Evaluating limits with more than one variable

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Kind of embarrassed, simple question:

Say we have limits of the form :

$$ \lim _{ x \rightarrow a, y \rightarrow b} f(x,y) $$

How do we test whether the limit exists and/or whether it is equal to a certain value L?

Do we need to have the limit be equal when we alternate the orders, i.e., to obtain the same limit by :

$$ \lim_{ y \rightarrow a}( \lim _{ x \rightarrow b})( f(x,y)) = $$

$$\lim_{ x \rightarrow b}( \lim _{ y \rightarrow a})( f(x,y)) $$ ?

Specifically, I was thinking of whether the limit as both $ x,n \rightarrow \infty$ of :

$$ e^x - (1 + \frac{x}{2!}+.....+ \frac{x^n}{n!}) $$

was $0$.  What order do we use?

We would have to check both whether the internal limit converges

Comment: If $I,J$ are open intervals containing $a$ and $b$, respectively, and $f:I\times J\to\mathbb R$ a real-valued function then $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} f(x,y)$$ exists if and only if the limit is the same no matter what "path" you take through the point $(a,b)$.

Comment: Thank you, how about in the case where one of the variables is discrete as in the second case where I want to find the limit (e^x - (1+x/2!+...+x^n/n!) as both x,n go to infinity?

Comment: That translates to: "For every $e > 0$, there exist $N\in \Bbb N, R\in \Bbb R$ such that if $n > N, x > R$, then $\left|\left(e^x - \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}\right) - L\right| < \epsilon$".